# R: Use model$xlevels to subset data to get to training data

Tags: r, model, training-data

Consider mtcars example:

```
model <- fit3 <- lm(mpg ~ factor(am)+wt+qsec+hp+drat, data = mtcars)
```

When you do

```
model$xlevels
```

we get the levels of the variable that was used for modeling.

If I want to use these level details to subset my data to get back to training data levels, assuming that the new data has more levels than previously used for modeling. How could I do that?

The intent is to avoid the error that there are new factors in the new data.

My prospective solution is:

```
td <- train_data
dim(td)
for(i in 1:length(model$xlevels)){
    print(i)
    mod.seg <- as.data.frame(model$xlevels[i])
    j = colnames(mod.seg)

    attributes <- paste0("subset(td, ",j," %in% unique(mod.seg$",j,"))")
    td <- unique(eval(parse(text=attributes)))
}
dim(td)
```

Comment: If the new data has a feature level that is not present in the training data that level unknown to the model. It cannot predict a value for that observation.

Comment: I agree, I have another code to ensure of that. This one is just to create the training data from the model object

Comment: I think you should reformulate your question because noone seems to understand what you want, me included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
td <- train_data
dim(td)
for(i in 1:length(model$xlevels)){
    print(i)
    mod.seg <- as.data.frame(model$xlevels[i])
    j = colnames(mod.seg)

    attributes <- paste0("subset(td, ",j," %in% unique(mod.seg$",j,"))")
    td <- unique(eval(parse(text=attributes)))
}
dim(td)
```